# Comparing two VBA codes for getting the SMTP address of a mailitem

Tags: vba, server, outlook, smtp, exchange-server

Is there a difference between the two codes below? Do they achieve the same thing, or bluntly put, which one is the better choice over the other dealing with unforeseen scenarios? objMail is a MailItem object on an Outlook Exchange Server.

Your feedback would appreciated.

[#1]

```
Dim Sender_email As String
    Sender_email = vbNullString

If objMail.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
    Sender_email = objMail.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
Else
    Sender_email = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
End If
```

[#2]

```
Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
Dim Sender_PA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Set Sender_PA = objMail.Sender.PropertyAccessor 
Dim Sender_email As String
    Sender_email = vbNullString

If objMail.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
    Sender_email = Sender_PA.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
Else
    Sender_email = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

[#1] is preferable - it is expensive to touch `objMail.Sender`, you should avoid that if yo ucan. #2 also assumes that `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` is always available. Generally, this is not the case, and you might also want to check `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES`.

Comment: Dmitry@ Thank you for your suggestions. I will probably stick with [#1]. On the other hand, If PR_SMTP_ADDRESS is unavailable, what value do I get for Sender_PA.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)? How do I use PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES in case PR_SMTP_ADDRESS becomes unavailable?

Comment: Latest versions of Outlook will raise an error if the property is not available. Older versions return null. PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES is a multivalued property, so yo uwill get an array of strings. You want the one prefixed with"SMTP:" (note the caps). Try it.